# Inserting post content into pages when using custom taxonomies

Tags: get-posts

I am inserting a snippet of text into posts when posts have a certain taxonomy.

I want this text to be editable by WP users n the admin area.

The following doesn't seem to want to do anything for me, admittedly I copied pasted and amended from another thread on here.

```
<?php
if ( has_term( 'ART', 'product_relevance' ) ) {
?>
<div class="row">
           <div class="notification col-lg-9 order-1">
<?php
    $my_id = 927;
    $post_id_927 = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
    $title = $post_id_927['post_content'];
?>

           </div>
</div>
 <?php
}
?>
```

The if statement works fine, it is just the block calling the post by ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code never outputs anything to the page:

```
<?php if(has_term('ART', 'product_relevance')):
   $my_post = get_post(927);
   if(isset($my_post->post_content)): ?>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="notification col-lg-9 order-1">
            <?php echo $my_post->post_content; ?>
         </div>
      </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Untested, but in essence you need to do something with the post content.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad it was something simple.